# Have rm not report when a file is missing?

Tags: rm

I have a bash script that I want to remove files from various directories. Frequently, they won't be there because they weren't generated and that's fine. Is there a way to get the script not to report that error, but if rm has some other output to report that?

Alternately, is there a better command to use to remove the file that'll be less noisy?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use the `-f` option.  It will silently ignore nonexistent files.

From `man rm`:

```
   -f, --force
          ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

[The "never prompt" part means that (a) `-f` overrides any previously specified `-i` or `-I` option, and (b) write-protected files will be deleted without asking.]

#### Example

Without `-f`, `rm` will complain about missing files:

```
$ rm nonesuch
rm: cannot remove ‘nonesuch’: No such file or directory
```

With `-f`, it will be silent:

```
$ rm -f nonesuch
$
```

Comment: Oh, I new that didn't prompt for removal, didn't realize it also ignored nonexistents. I totally skipped over that when looking at man. :-) Thank you. I'll mark this as the answer soon as I'm allowed.

Answer (score 13):

If your requirement is that `rm` does not complain about missing files, but that you also want any *other* output from `rm`, my suggestion would be to first test for the target file's existence, and only call `rm` (*without* the `-f` flag) if the file actually exists.

```
# rest of script
# ...
[ -e "$file" ] && rm "$file"
# ...
# rest of script
```

Calling `rm -f` on a file that, for example, doesn't have user-write permissions, will remove the file *and* also not emit the normal prompt for that scenario.

In case you wanted to use the same idea with multiple files, I would create a function definition, like:

```
qrm() {
  for f
  do
    [ -e "$f" ] && rm "$f"
  done
}
```

Use it like: `qrm file1 file2-does-not-exist *.txt etc here`

Comment: It's worth being aware of the very slight chance of a race condition where the file is deleted (or created) between the test and the removal, but I can't imagine that being relevant in any typical situation where one would be using a shell script.

Comment: @DavidZ How could that happen? This tests if something exists and then if that succeeds, removes it so it has to get back a response before the removal starts.

Answer (score 9):

You stated that you still want to see other output from the `rm` command when you run it, but using the `-f` option will suppress those. You will need to filter STDERR for what you want, which is a little tricky, given you want everything else to show.

You will want to use a command like this:

```
rm -f filename 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -v 'No such file or directory'
```

Command explained:

- `-f` argument is to force through and not prompt for confirmation or errors
- `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-` is to switch around STDOUT and STDERR for filtering (you can read more about this [here](http://burgerbum.com/stderr_pipe.html) if wanted
- `| grep -v 'No such file or directory'` is filtering out the message you do not want to see

Now, if you just wanted to suppress error messages entirely, you could run the following command:

```
rm filename 2> /dev/null
```

This command redirects STDERR to /dev/null so you will not see it when you run the command.

Comment: (AFAICS) `rm` without `-v` never outputs to stdout, only stderr, so in this case you could just `2>&1 | grep` without the dance which is useful more generally,

Answer (score 5):

This is a hack, but you could always `touch` the file about to be removed. If it doesn't exist, it will be created so `rm` can remove it.

Comment: I like this, except for the performance - how costly is it to touch several K's of files as opposed to only deleting the ones that don't exist?

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can use the `find` command with the `-delete` option. This will (obviously) only delete the files it finds so it never warns if none are. An example might be:

```
find /var/log/triffids/ -name "*.log" -mtime 30 -delete
```

which would search the `/var/log/triffids/` directory and  delete all files with the `.log` suffix which have not been modified for more than 30 days.

It is always a good idea to run these commands *without* the `-delete` option first, to make sure it's finding the files you expect.

Comment: I like this option and will consider a change. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `--force` (`-f`) option of `rm`:

> -f, --force
>
> ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-f` as it will, according to the man page:

> Attempt to remove the files without prompting for
>   confirmation, regardless of the file's permissions.  If the file does
>   not exist, do not display a diagnostic message or modify the exit
>   status to reflect an error. also remember The -f option overrides any
>   previous -i options.

```
rm -f xyz-directory
```

will not prompt you anything, and will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

There are two main ways: If you add the -f option, it will not show the "doesn't exist" error and two: (works for almost any command) instead of just doing "thecommand" do "thecommand 2>/dev/null" where "thecommand" is the command you're doing.

Comment: I was avoiding the piping because I don't want to loose other errors that might come up. I don't know what they would be.