# alternative options to rm -f

Tags: command-line, rm

I'd like to run a command line:

```
cd ~/www/tmp/; rm -P 2*
```

But I get an error if there are no files starting with 2.

You would think I would want to use `-f`, however:

```
-f      Attempt to remove the files without prompting for confirmation, regardless of the file's permissions.  If the file does not exist, do not display a diagnostic message or modify the exit status to reflect an error.
```

And I *do* care about file permissions- if there's something weird going on, I'd prefer the command abort.  I only want to suppress 'do not exist' errors.

I've looked at some other questions with 'rm errors', and found these two which seem (kinda) relevant:

[Delete files and directories by their names. No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/delete-files-and-directories-by-their-names-no-such-file-or-directory)

But, I don't understand everything going on in the answers to this question, and don't know that I need it?

The `touch` hack suggested in this question:

[Have rm not report when a file is missing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280067/have-rm-not-report-when-a-file-is-missing)

Seems workable, as I don't think I mind the performance hit (but what type of performance hit would you take? - ie: is this a reasonably scalable technique, or am I just learning very bad habits?)

I'm not sure how I'd do an `if-then` within the command line.

Are there any other options for a simple command line cut-n-paste cleanup?

Would `find -delete` work better for my case?  If so, why?

---

error in question:

```
rm: 2*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error is from your shell, not  `rm`, so you'll need to say what that is.

Comment: Are you using `zsh` as your interactive shell? Are you getting a `No matches found` error?

Comment: @MichaelHomer No, the error is from rm. The shell merely passed on the string `2*` to rm instead of expanding it to a list of files. Look at the error in question: it says that rm is complaining, not sh/bas/zsh/...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To only call `rm -P` for *existing* regular files whose names match a pattern in a directory (but not below):

```
find directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'pattern' -exec rm -P {} +
```

E.g.,

```
find ~/www/tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '2*' -exec rm -P {} +
```

To match only non-directories, use `! -type d` in place of `-type f`. The difference is that `! -type d` would be true for a wider range of file types (symbolic links, named pipes, sockets, etc.)

Since you want to be prompted for some conditions on the files found, you should *not* use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm` since that works as `rm -f`.

Remove `-maxdepth 1` to let `find` look in subdirectories recursively.

Comment: Though `! -type d` might be closer to `rm 2*`, I think?

Comment: So, I'd have to add -P to get that functionality?: `find ~/www/tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '2*' -exec rm -P {} +`

Comment: @user3082 Yes, I forgot that you wanted to use `-P` too.

Comment: Thanks @muru, I actually want `-type f`, but didn't know how to make `rm` act like that - so @Kusalanada's suggestion was spot-on, and the differentiation / explanation is great for learning.

Comment: @user3082 you'd probably have to use your shell's extended globbing (e.g., `rm 2*(.)` in zsh).